# VISUAL and EDITOR variables aren't defined

Tags: linux, bash, centos, environment-variables, emacs

I'm using CentOs 6 and learning about command line editing modes. The VISUAL and EDITOR variables aren't defined in my system and `printenv` or `env` commands don't show them. My X terminal starts in `emacs` mode, so where this default configuration is defined? And also I can't see any configuration in `.bashrc` and `.bash_profile` files.

Comment: `My X terminal starts in emacs mode` - do you mean that `Bash` starts in its default Emacs mode or that Emacs is run when `edit-and-execute-command` is called?

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk yes, I mean bash starts in emacs mode and I want to know where can I find this default configuration and how to change it?

Comment: When Bash starts interactively, command line editing is enabled by default which uses Readline library which comes with a set of Emacs-like keybindings and the line editing commands are similar to those of Emac...and the readline startup file is `.inputrc`. links:https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Line-Editing.html#Command-Line-Editing   https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Readline-Init-File.html#Readline-Init-File

Answer (score 4):

If command line editing mode in `bash` is not set with `set -o emacs` or `set -o vi`, the `bash` shell will default to using `emacs` editing mode.

This is documented in the `bash` manual (when the manual talks about `set -o emacs` in the section dealing with the built-in command `set`):

> `emacs`
>
> Use an `emacs`-style command line editing
>           interface.  **This is enabled by default** when the
>           shell is interactive, unless the shell is
>           started with the `--noediting` option.  This also
>           affects the editing interface used for `read -e`.

`bash` does not seem to derive its command line editing mode from `$EDITOR` or `$VISUAL`.